# Overflow on UILabels

Tags: iphone, uitableview, overflow, uilabel, line-breaks

I have a table view that I am customizing and I am adding a UILabel as a subview of the contentView, and I want the number of lines to be relatively consistent.

I set the `numberOfLines` property to be 3 so it can't go more than that, but there are still some that overflow onto the 4th line.

If it overflows, I want to add a a trailing `...`

How can I figure out if it overflows? I've tried truncating at different character counts of my string, but since I am using `lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap` the number of characters doesn't really predict the number of lines.

Is there a way to find out the number of lines your `UILabel` is using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap`, just set the numberOfLines property to 3.